# Collecting Student Data Dynamically with java

Tags: java

I tried to develop a program to collect Student data dynamically but in return during run time it is showing main class exception. Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
    String arr[]=null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //int x=0;
        String[] arr =new String[2];

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("\t\t\tStudent Record Menu");

        System.out.println("\t\tEnter Student Details");

        int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Full name:");
            String name = input.next(); 

            Array.set(arr,  i, name);
            System.out.println("Age:");
            String age = input.next();
            Array.set(arr,  i, age);
            System.out.println("Course:");
            String course = input.next();
            Array.set(arr,  i, course);
            System.out.println("Year:");
            String year = input.next();
            Array.set(arr,  i, year);
            System.out.println("Section:");
            String section = input.next();
            Array.set(arr,  i, section);
        }     

        for(String s:arr){
            System.out.println("The Values are:"+s.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't showing any errors, but it is just not executing. Please help me understand what I have to change in the code.

Comment: which error have you ?

Comment: @Prajna The output will be printed as ** The Values are:2**

Comment: @prajna Have you using any IDE to run the code?

Comment: For each input you are overwriting the value of the array at the same position, so naturally in the end you will have 2 times the value of "Section".

Comment: and I'm getting main class exception

Comment: this is not javascript, please remove the tag. java and javascript are NOT the same thing

Comment: And if you are getting an exception, tell us what the exception is. Post a stacktrace and tell us which line it points to.

Answer (score -1):

In your example you are only storing the section, because you overwriting the previous data that you stored.
see the output..

`Student Record Menu
        Enter Student Details
Full name:
1
Age:
2
Course:
3
Year:
4
Section:
5
Full name:
6
Age:
7
Course:
8
Year:
9
Section:
0
The Values are:5
The Values are:0`